# Writing good "alt" content?

Tags: html, accessibility

What is it the best practice with regards the alt attribute of images?

For example, say I have an image with a caption that says "We look after our staff" and the accompanying image is a picture of a man looking out of a van windows towards the camera, for the alt content should I have something like:

"We look after our staff" (A copy of the image caption)

OR

"A picture of a man looking out of a van windows towards the camera" (A description of the image)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Taken from the w3 spec, reworded;](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-alt-techniques/)

There is no "wrong" or "right" way of writing alt tags, as it is relative to the context. For example, take the following scenario; on your site, the end user is asked to pick his favourite colour:

[image]

The alt tags would be as follows:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="red.html"><img src="red.jpeg" alt="Red"></a></li>
<li><a href="green.html"><img src="green.jpeg" alt="Green"></a></li>
<li><a href="blue.html"><img src="blue.jpeg" alt="Blue"></a></li>
</ul>
```

A second scenario is if you had a logo which in turn links through to the website, the alt tag should be a description of the link:

[image]

A well written alt tag would be:

```
<a href="http://w3.org">
<img src="images/w3c_home.png" width="72" height="48" alt="W3C web site">
</a>
```

More applicable for YOUR scenario would be the following examples.

> Here is an example of an image closely related to the subject matter of the page content but not directly discussed. An image of a painting inspired by a poem, on a page reciting that poem. The following snippet shows an example. The image is a painting titled the "Lady of Shallot", it is inspired by the poem and its subject matter is derived from the poem. Therefore it is strongly recommended that a text alternative is provided. There is a short description of the content of the image in the alt attribute and a link below the image to a longer description located at the bottom of the document. At the end of the longer description there is also a link to further information about the painting.

[image]

Which should have the following code for the alt text

```
<header><h1>The Lady of Shalott</h1>
<h2>A poem by Alfred Lord Tennyson</h2></header>

<img src="shalott.jpeg" alt="Painting of a  young woman with long hair, sitting in a wooden boat. ">
<p><a href="#des">Description of the painting</a>.</p>

<!-- Full Recitation of Alfred, Lord Tennyson's Poem.  -->

...
...
...
<p id="des">The woman in the painting is wearing a flowing white dress. A large piece of intricately 
patterned fabric is draped over the side. In her right hand she holds the chain mooring the boat. Her expression 
is mournful. She stares at a crucifix lying in front of her. Beside it are three candles. Two have blown out. 
<a href="http://bit.ly/5HJvVZ">Further information about the painting</a>.</p>
```

However.... sometimes an alt tag can be left out all together. For example, if you had the above image with a contextual description relative to the image on the page directly below:

[image]

> Join us for our medieval theme nights every Friday at Boaters Bar, on
>   the riverside, Kingston upon Thames.

For the above example, either of the following solutions would be conforming:

```
<p><img src="shalott.jpeg" alt=""></p>
<p>Join us for our medieval theme nights every Friday at 
Boaters Bar,on the riverside, Kingston upon Thames.</p>
```

Or

```
<p><img src="shalott.jpeg" alt="Painting of a woman in a white flowing dress, sitting in a small boat."></p>
<p>Join us for our medieval theme nights every Friday at Boaters Bar,
 on the riverside, Kingston upon  Thames.</p>
```

Comment: Short answer... the last example in my list will apply to yours

Comment: Awesome, just the kind of explanation I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

**Extract from w3.org**

> When an image contains words that are important to understanding the
>   content, the alt text should include those words. This will allow the
>   alt text to play the same function on the page as the image. Note that
>   it does not necessarily describe the visual characteristics of the
>   image itself but must convey the same meaning as the image.

**Example 1**

> An image on a Website provides a link to a free newsletter. The image
>   contains the text "Free newsletter. Get free recipes, news, and more.
>   Learn more." The alt text matches the text in the image.

**Example 2**

> An image on a Web site depicts the floor plan of a building. The image
>   is an image map with each room an interactive map area. The alt text
>   is "The building's floor plan. Select a room for more information
>   about the purpose or content of the room." The instruction to "select
>   a room" indicates that the image is interactive.

http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H37

Answer (score 0):

Warning: this answer is rather subjective.

I use this attribute especially at images having a special function. For example a image of a disk on which the user can click for saving something. Then the value of alt would be "save".

But I don't think you should give a description of every picture. Just say "gallery image" or something like this.

Comment: It makes sense to use it to describe images that have functions, hadn't thought of that situation!

Comment: Alt attributes are _required_ for all images, not ones with "special usuage." NEVER use stock alt's like kuh suggested. If the image isn't important give it a null alt (alt=""). This tells a screen reader to ignore it, and skip over it. Stock alts are extremely annoying, imagine being told to do a 2 page survey and surprise it is really 10pages.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, the `alt` is for the text replacement for the imagine.

Many cases, I leave have `alt = ""` because there is no text that would replace that imagine.

Other times, just a single character is best:

```
<img src="fancy_bullet_point.gif" alt="*">
```

Just remember the basic rule of thumb: If you did not have the image, what would you put there instead?